# Route propagation from virtual private gateway in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, gateway

I stumbled upon understanding of the idea of the *route propagation* in AWS. It is said in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html):

> Route propagation allows a virtual private gateway to automatically propagate routes to the route tables so that you don't need to manually enter VPN routes to your route tables. You can enable or disable route propagation.

May be it is a self-explanatory feature, but I completely don't understand what it means. In particular I am confused about the following: does it mean I don't need to explicitly add a route with some destination and a target as VPWG? Will the virtual private gateway automatically add all CIDR blocks from its VPN connections to the route table??

I am seeking for some example for dummies which can illustrate what this feature gives to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, that is what it means, otherwise, you have to do it manually

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPNRoutingTypes.html#vpn-route-priority

> Route tables determine where network traffic is directed. In your route table, you must add a route for your remote network and specify the virtual private gateway as the target. This enables traffic from your VPC that's destined for your remote network to route via the virtual private gateway and over one of the VPN tunnels. You can enable route propagation for your route table to automatically propagate your network routes to the table for you.